# replacing text box with checkbox mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and mysql to update user data inside of the database as admin, i have a text box which allows the admin to input approved or not approved, now i want to try change the text box for the approved or not approved into a check box where the admin can just click on the check box approved and the data will be updated according to the user which was selected as im not really sure how to go about it. thanks

```
<?php
 require('connection.php');
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $prescription = $_FILES['prescription']['name'];
        $image_tmp = $_FILES['prescription']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"medical-prescription/$prescription");
        $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET approved=?,prescription=?  WHERE id=?");
        $approved=$_POST['approved'];

        $sql->bind_param("ssi",$approved, $prescription,$_GET["id"]);

        if($sql->execute()) {
            $success_message = "Edited Successfully";
        } else {
            $error_message = "Problem in Editing Record";
        }

    }
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
    $sql->bind_param("i",$_GET["id"]);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
    $conn->close();
?>

<?php if(!empty($success_message)) { ?>
<div class="success message"><?php echo $success_message; ?></div>
<?php } if(!empty($error_message)) { ?>
<div class="error message"><?php echo $error_message; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<form  method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>approved</label>
            <input type="text" name="approved" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $row["approved"]?>">
            <label>Medical prescription</label>
             <input type="file" name="prescription" id="prescription" required/><br>
            <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit" class="demo-form-submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:
Change HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="approved" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $row["approved"]?>"> Approved?
```

php:

Replace this:

```
...    
$approved=$_POST['approved'];
...
```

with:

```
...
$approved=(isset($_POST['approved'])) ? $_POST['approved']: "Not approved"; // Or any other text value what you use
...
```

Here is formatted code:

```
<?php
 require('connection.php');
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $prescription = $_FILES['prescription']['name'];
        $image_tmp = $_FILES['prescription']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"medical-prescription/$prescription");
        $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET approved=?,prescription=?  WHERE id=?");
        //HERE WE CHANGE
        $approved=(isset($_POST['approved'])) ? $_POST['approved']: "Not approved";

        $sql->bind_param("ssi",$approved, $prescription,$_GET["id"]);

        if($sql->execute()) {
            $success_message = "Edited Successfully";
        } else {
            $error_message = "Problem in Editing Record";
        }

    }
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
    $sql->bind_param("i",$_GET["id"]);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
    $conn->close();
?>

<?php if(!empty($success_message)) { ?>
<div class="success message"><?php echo $success_message; ?></div>
<?php } if(!empty($error_message)) { ?>
<div class="error message"><?php echo $error_message; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<form  method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>approved</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="approved" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $row["approved"]?>"> Approve?
            <label>Medical prescription</label>
             <input type="file" name="prescription" id="prescription" required/><br>
            <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit" class="demo-form-submit">
</form>
```

Here is the test:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  alert("Submitted data: {" + data + '}');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="approved" class="txtField" value="Yes"> Approved?
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: What is not working? i just added a case test

Comment: how is it being updated in the database tho? coz im trying to add the approved and not approved in the sql statement

Comment: You `bind` this parameter in to the statement and execute it.

Comment: dont no how im going to implement the example you did into my sql statement

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: do i need to add something in the sql update statement coz noting is being added to the db

Comment: check if you can execute same statement in phpmyadmin or terminal to update specific row.